# MongoDB NodeJS Indexes, no consigo listar los indices de una colección

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

No consigo listar los índices de una colección usando el `Driver API` para NodeJS. He probado con los métodos de `collection` (`indexes`, `listIndexes` y `indexInformation`), pero no consigo que se listen como cuando se hace a través del `shell` (en el mismo formato). La conexión se establece y se itera pero no recupera los índices. Aquí dejo, mas o menos, el código del *script*:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const collections = require('./collections.json');

(async function() {
  const url = process.env.urlDB;
  const dbName = 'test';
  const client = new MongoClient(url);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);

    collections.forEach( async collection => {
        console.log(collection.name);
        const col = await db.collection(collection.name)
        const idx = col.listIndexes()
        console.log('Indexes:', idx);       
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }

  client.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con db.collection.getIndexes() que retorna una lista de documentos que identifican y describen los índices existentes en el collection.

Puedes chequear en la propia documentacion de mongo:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/

Comment: db.collection.getIndexes() es para el command shell de mongo. Necesito hacerlo desde el API driver de NodeJS. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en la forma en la que usas los métodos y la forma en la que manejas el resultado de los mismos.

El método [`listIndexes()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#listIndexes) del [Driver Nativo de MongoDB para NodeJS](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/) devuelve un Objeto de tipo [CommandCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/CommandCursor.html) y no una lista con los índices de las colecciones.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución parte de leer la documentación del método, y sobre todo entender el proceso asíncrono asociado y manejar el resultado adecuadamente.

Mi respuesta será algo larga, así que aquí va un resumen:

**Resumen**

Para obtener los índices de una colección de MongoDB tal como se obtienen usando el Shell de Mongo con el método [`getIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes), debemos convertir el resultado de la llamada a `listIndexes()` en un Objeto iterable, usando [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/CommandCursor.html#toArray), el cual nos devolverá una lista con la información que deseamos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
db.collection(collection.name, (error, col) => {
  // ...
  col.listIndexes().toArray((error, listOfIndex) => {
    // ...
    console.log(listOfIndex); // <- array cuyos elementos se corresponden con los índices de cada colección.
  });
});
```

El resultado anterior produce una salida parecida a la siguiente:

```js
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_', ns: 'test.books' },
  {
    v: 2,
    unique: true,
    key: { title: 1 },
    name: 'title_1',
    ns: 'test.books',
    background: true
  }
]
```

Como se puede apreciar es la misma salida que produce el comando `db.collection.getIndexes()` del Shell de Mongo.

---

**tl;dr**

El método `listIndexes()` del Driver Nativo de MongoDB para NodeJS devuelve un Objeto de tipo `CursorCommand`. El cual es un [*cursor*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(base_de_datos)), como los que toda la vida han existido en las Bases de Datos.

Este cursor en particular tiene varios métodos que podemos encontrar en la documentación. Como el método [`next()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/CommandCursor.html#next) (típico en cualquier cursor de Base de Datos).

Por ejemplo podemos hacer:

```js
const cursor = await col.listIndexes();
let index = await cursor.next();
console.log(index);
```

El resultado del comando anterior puede verse así:

```
{ v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_', ns: 'test.books' }
```

Ahora, supongamos que quiero mostrar 1 a 1 todos los índices encontrados, ¿necesito saber de antemano cuantos índices hay?, la respuesta es no. El cursor tiene un método llamado [`hasNext()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/CommandCursor.html#hasNext) que devuelve un booleano, siendo `true` si existen más registros en el cursor, y siendo `false` en caso contrario.

Podríamos hacer algo como esto:

```js
const cursor = await db.collection(collection.name).listIndexes();
let elemento = 0;
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  let index = await cursor.next();
  console.log(`Elemento del cursor número: ${++elemento}`);
  console.log(index);
}
```

Lo cual nos produce un resultado parecido al siguiente:

```js
Elemento del cursor número: 1
{ v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_', ns: 'test.books' }
Elemento del cursor número: 2
{
  v: 2,
  unique: true,
  key: { title: 1 },
  name: 'title_1',
  ns: 'test.books',
  background: true
}
```

Como puedes observar el cursor es iterado elemento por elemento y cada elemento es mostrado en pantalla.

Si deseamos poner cada elemento en una lista podríamos hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
const cursor = await db.collection(collection.name).listIndexes();
let indices = [];
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  let index = await cursor.next();
  indices.push(index);
}
console.log(indices);
```

Lo cual produce el siguiente resultado:

```js
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_', ns: 'test.books' },
  {
    v: 2,
    unique: true,
    key: { title: 1 },
    name: 'title_1',
    ns: 'test.books',
    background: true
  }
]
```

Por último, todo este código lo podemos simplificar usando el método [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/CommandCursor.html#toArray), de esta forma nuestro cursor nos devuelve directamente una lista con los elementos. Por ejemplo:

```js
const cursor = await db.collection(collection.name).listIndexes();
const indices = await cursor.toArray();
console.log(indices);
```

Lo cual nos proporciona la salida esperada.

Tu método puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```js
const db = client.db(dbName);
collections.forEach(async collection => {
  const cursor = await db.collection(collection.name).listIndexes();
  let indices = await cursor.toArray();
  console.log(indices);
});
```

Espero que con esto puedas resolver el problema de obtener los índices de tus colecciones en MongoDB usando el Driver de NodeJS.